# a brush effect in java

Tags: java, graphics

I want to achieve the effect of java in the brush, the mouse returned to the point, move the mouse faster, thinner lines.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to achieve the effect of a paintbrush in a free-hand drawing tool written in Java, such that the thickness of the line depends on the speed the mouse is moving? (By the way, that's not how real paintbrushes behave.)

Comment: Thanks,Because I am writing a java procedure, hope to pass the ambulation of mouse to express this effect.I ain't really either to understand how real paintbrushes behave.Maybe ,you can tell me.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program which demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

*This program is not perfect, but should get you started with what you are trying to build.*

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PaintBrush {

    JFrame f;
    Canvas c;
    int x=-1, y=-1;

    public PaintBrush() {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        c = new Canvas() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                // super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        f.getContentPane().add(c);
        c.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if(x==-1){
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                }
                int diffx =  Math.abs(x - e.getX());
                int diffy =  Math.abs(y - e.getY());
                System.out.println("diffx:"+diffx+"\t"+"diffy:"+diffy);
                int speed = (int) Math.sqrt((diffx + diffy));
                if(speed>1){
                    c.getGraphics().fillOval(x, y, 20-speed*2, 20-speed*2);
                }else {
                    c.getGraphics().fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
                }
                System.out.print("Speed:"+speed + "\t");
                System.out.println("x:"+e.getX());
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
            }
        });
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintBrush();

    }
```